# Where does RTC stores Date and Time in SRAM or EPROM

Tags: linux, date, timestamps, real-time

I gone through some of the datasheet regarding RTC like MCP79411X,

- but having confusion like where RTC stores timestamp in sram or eeprom,
- suppose RTC store Time in sram means it is volatile memory when no power data will be eraised,
- when power is der where it stores timestamp.
- whether date and time will be updated everytime.

Answer (score 2):

RTCs are typically battery backed. EEPROM is somewhat slower to program (and esp. to reprogram, requiring an explicit erase step), and for data that changes *every second*, the limited number write cycles the device can handle might start being an issue. (Or you'd need some sort of wear leveling, increasing complexity.) That's one of the reasons why your motherboard usually has a CR2032 coin-style battery in there somewhere.

With that MCP79411X chip in specific, [the datasheet](https://www.mouser.fi/datasheet/2/268/22266A-47240.pdf) (which I found from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.fi/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/MCP79411-I-ST)) says it quite clearly: the chip is described as an "I<sup>2</sup>C™ Real-Time Clock/Calendar with EEPROM, SRAM, Unique ID **and Battery Switchover**" on the top of the page, and the "Features" listing starts with "Real-Time Clock/Calendar (RTCC), Battery Backed..."

Answer (score 0):

If you go in to the specifications you will see such chips are battery powered. And as this chip is created on CMOS technology it consume very low amount of energy.

To answer your question: variable data is stored in RAM. EEPROM memory is used to store the frequency of the crystal (usually 32768 Hz), Unique ID and MAC addresses.