# Real Time clock regarding timestamp storage

Tags: linux, date, hardware, timestamps, real-time

I gone through some of the datasheet regarding RTC like MCP79411X,

- but having confusion like where RTC stores timestamp in sram or eeprom,
  [image]
  can anyone explain me the flow of the below fig
  suppose timestamp store in SRAM then I2C connected to EEPROM how does the timestamp sended to MCU how interaction takes place

Comment: _"but having confusion like where RTC stores timestamp in sram or eeprom"_ -- didn't [you just ask this a day before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/710389/170373)? _"how does the timestamp sended to MCU how interaction takes place"_ -- the datasheet describes the communication protocol, and there's a number of resources on IIC online. Is there something in particular you need clarification on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extracted the image from the [manual from](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22266A.pdf). The image presents a block diagram. Most block diagrams are meant to explain some general concept. That block diagram seems to indicate where is power being used (the red and blue lines, except the two of the crystal). External power feeds some blocks. Battery feeds some other blocks. The block diagram doesn't show any concept of data use or storage.

You may take a look at this block diagram from [this other manual](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP79410-MCP79411-MCP79412-Battery-BackedI2C-RTCC-20002266J.pdf):

[image: /home/immf/Downloads/MCP7941X-figure-1-2]

In that you can see the paths for data exchange. The i<sup>2</sup>C is able to access (read and write) to both types of memories.

The EEPROM doesn't require power to retain its values. And is designed to be changed few times.

The SRAM is where all the time values are stored and it is described (in both manuals) in section `4.1 RTCC MEMORY MAP` in your original manual or in section `FIGURE 5-1: MEMORY MAP` in the other manual. In both manuals, anyway, it is stated that the SRAM memory stores the present time, the two alarms, a couple of power timestamps and 64 bytes of general data for the user.

So, in short, time is definitely **stored in SRAM**.

Comment: thank you for your answer helped lot and i few queries like what will be stored in EEPROM ?  anyway timestamp stored in SRAM as u told , I2C used to interact both memories then from where I2C fetch data in SRAM or EEPROM to send the processor.

Comment: .... *I2C fetch data in SRAM or EEPROM* from SRAM or EEPROM. @SukanyaU

Comment: I2C fetch data from SRAM or EEPROM to send processor.@QuartzCristal

Comment: Is there a question in there ? @SukanyaU

Comment: yes from which memory I2C fetch data to send  processor. like I2C is the communication protocol so through SDA only master and slave interact right so I2C need to send data to processor from which memory of RTC it picks data and send SRAM or EEPROM, what is stored in eeprom  @QuartzCrista

Comment: @SukanyaU You are being quite dense. If the command sent through the i2C protocol is to read from the SRAM, then the data is read from the SRAM. If the command sent using the i2C protocol is to read some byte from the EEPROM, then the byte is read from the EEPROM and sent back. Is it clear now?.

Comment: yes Thank You @QuartzCristal

Answer (score 0):

> confusion like where RTC stores timestamp in sram or eeprom

The figure doesn't specify that.

> can anyone explain me the flow of the below fig suppose timestamp store in SRAM then I2C connected to EEPROM how does the timestamp sended to MCU how interaction takes place

I hope I understand these 2.75 sentences correctly!
So, what you're asking is

> How is the information at which time a trigger should take place exchanged between MCU and this RTC chip?

And the answer is that the block labeled "I²C" is in fact a small specific processor for commands that the MCU sends via I²C. It gets a command to reprogram the alarm times with the new alarm time. So it does that.